# Setting up replicated repositories in Plastic SCM

Tags: version-control, repository, plasticscm

So we're trying to set up replicated repositories using PlasticSCM, one in the US, and one in Australia and running into a bit of a snag.

The US configuration is Active Directory, the AU configuration is User/Password.  This in itself is not a big deal, I've already set up the SID translation table.

The problem is with plasticscm's replicate command itself.  This is the command which should replicate from the US to AU, run ON the AU server.

```
cm replicate br:/main@rep:default@repserver:US:8084 rep:myrep@repserver:AU:9090 --trmode=name --trtable=trans.txt --authdata=ActiveDirectory:192.168.1.3:389:john.doe@factory.com:fPBea2rPsQaagEW3pKNveA==:dc=factory,dc=com
```

The part I'm stuck at is the authdata part (the above is an EXAMPLE only).   How can I generate the obscured password?  I think it's the only thing preventing these two repositories from talking to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've solved my own problem.
To get that "authdata" string, you need to configure your client to how you need to authenticate.
  Then navigate to c:[users directory][username]\Local Settings\Application Data\plastic.
  Pick up the client.conf and extract the string from the SecurityConfig element in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Check the new GUI [here](http://www.plasticscm.com/demos/distributed_intro/distributed_intro.html). It's a little bit easier.